# Store the same ID in both the tables in multithreaded code

Tags: java, database, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I have started working on a project in which I have two tables in a different database with different schemas. So I will be having two different connection parameters to connect to the database. And after connecting to each database, I need to insert in those two tables using the sql given in corresponding table.

And I am supposed to insert in all the two tables or any one of them using JDBC depending on the command line parameters. So that means a single thread will be inserting into Table1 and Table2 or any one of them.

Command Line Parameters:- Here 10 is number of threads, 100 is number of tasks, table1 and table2 are table names.

```
10 100 table1 table2
```

Below is my code. In this code what will happen is- suppose if we are passing only one table named `table1`, then it will insert into that table by using the SQL meant for table1.

And also I need to insert same `id` in both `table1` and `table2` and that `id` is being passed as `AtomicInteger` to Constructor `Task`. So that means if `id is 1`, then this `1 id` should be there both in `table1` and `table2`.

```
 final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(1);

 ExecutorService service = Executors. newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

 for (int i = 0; i < noOfTasks * noOfThreads; i++) {

      for (String arg : tableNames) {
          String url = (String) prop.get(arg + ".url");
          String user = (String) prop.get(arg + ".user");
          String password = (String) prop.get(arg + ".password");
          String driver = (String) prop.get(arg + ".driver");
          String suffix = (String) prop.get(arg + ".suffix");
          String sql = (String) prop.get(arg + ".sql");

          service.submit( new Task(id, url, user, password, driver, sql, suffix));
        }
    }
```

Below is the Task class that implements Runnable interface

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicInteger id ;
    private final String url ;
    private final String username ;
    private final String password ;
    private final String sql ;
    private final String driver ;
    private final String suffix ;

    public Task(AtomicInteger id, String url, String user, String password, String driver, String sql, String suffix) {
        this.id = id;
        this.url = url;
        this.username = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.driver = driver;
        this.sql = sql;
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

           dbConnection = getDBConnection(url , username , password , driver );
           callableStatement = dbConnection .prepareCall(sql);

           int userId = id .getAndIncrement();

           callableStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(userId));

        //other callableStatement


        callableStatement.executeUpdate();
       }
    }
```

So If I am running the above program with multiple threads like Number of Threads as `10` and Number of Tasks as `1000` and `id` if I choose as `1`.

**Then in both the tables same id is not there**, meaning id 1 will be there only in one table either `table1` or `table2`. The only reason I can think of is- `id` is `AtomicInteger` so everytime it will get a new `id` for each thread. Is there any way I can use the same id to insert in each of the tables? And then making sure id is `PrimaryKey` so each thread will get a new id if it is inserting again in those tables.

Comment: Make your counter static, so there's only one?  Of course, then you have to agree as to who is responsible to increment it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you are saying, I should make this `private final AtomicInteger id ;` as static in the Task class right? I tried that by changing to static like this `private static AtomicInteger id ;` but the result is same and it's not working. `id 1` goes only in one table.

Comment: Like I said, you have to agree to have only one thread increment it for each update operation.  The others just reference the incremented value.

Comment: Make sense to me. So how can I achieve this thing? Any sample example will make me understand better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should define the counter as static to avoid duplicate `PrimaryKey`:

```
static AtomicInteger id;
```

Then move the increment code to the main loop like this(do not forget to remove the `int userId = id .getAndIncrement();` in the `Task` class):

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfTasks * noOfThreads; i++) {
  // add following line
  int userId = id.getAndIncrement();

  for (String arg : tableNames) {
      String url = (String) prop.get(arg + ".url");
      String user = (String) prop.get(arg + ".user");
      String password = (String) prop.get(arg + ".password");
      String driver = (String) prop.get(arg + ".driver");
      String suffix = (String) prop.get(arg + ".suffix");
      String sql = (String) prop.get(arg + ".sql");

      service.submit( new Task(id, url, user, password, driver, sql, suffix));
    }
}
```

Besides, as the `id` counter is kept in memory, you might need to persistent it, otherwise it would be reset to 0 after restarting your application.